# Graph not showing in principal component analysis using python

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

How to show the graph image in my output for Principal Component Analysis?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (8, 8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.set_xlabel('Principal Component 1', fontsize = 15)
ax.set_ylabel('Principal Component 2', fontsize = 15)
ax.set_title('2 Component PCA', fontsize = 20)

targets = ['Iris - setosa', 'Iris - versicolor', 'Iris - virginica']
colors = ['r', 'g', 'b']

for target, color in zip(targets, colors):
    indicesToKeep = finalDF['target'] == target     
    ax.scatter(finalDF.loc[indicesToKeep, 'Principal Component 1'],
              finalDF.loc[indicesToKeep, 'Principal Component 2'],
              c = color, s = 50)

ax.legend(targets)
ax.grid()
ax.show()
```

Here is the error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-d87d089bc5f1> in <module>
         16 ax.legend(targets)
         17 ax.grid()
--->     18 ax.show()

AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'show'
```

[image: the plots are not showing up]

How to show the graph as there is no plots out there and show attribute is not working?

Comment: To show a pyplot figure, use `plt.show()`.

Answer (score 0):

Only correction here is: in last line replace `axis.show()` by `fig.show()`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (8, 8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.set_xlabel('Principal Component 1', fontsize = 15)
ax.set_ylabel('Principal Component 2', fontsize = 15)
ax.set_title('2 Component PCA', fontsize = 20)

targets = ['Iris - setosa', 'Iris - versicolor', 'Iris - virginica']
colors = ['r', 'g', 'b']

for target, color in zip(targets, colors):
    indicesToKeep = finalDF['target'] == target     
    ax.scatter(finalDF.loc[indicesToKeep, 'Principal Component 1'],
              finalDF.loc[indicesToKeep, 'Principal Component 2'],
              c = color, s = 50)

ax.legend(targets)
ax.grid()
fig.show()
```

Comment: but my plots are not showing up..it is showing this...……C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py:445: UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.
  % get_backend())

Comment: because as it says:'your environment is a non-GUI backend' you can try saving the fig instead of ```fig.show()``` try ```fig.savefig("fig_name.png")``` remember to add the format in the name like '.png' or '.jpg' or u may try any other environment.